# Firefox bug with multiple nested z-index elements and preserve-3d

Tags: html, css, z-index

I tried to google it and checked similar questions here, but i found nothing :(

http://codepen.io/suez/pen/d563d6819f7df5c0b0f55db3e9bfc085?editors=010 - here is a demo. It works perfectly in chrome, but i can't hover/click button of centered block in Firefox, dev-tools inspector saying that i'm hovering `.rotater` element, when it's have `z-index: 3` and `.inner` element have `z-index: 5`. All elements properly nested, have `position: absolute/relative` and childs have bigger z-index than their parents. Also main container `.scene` have perspective property, `.level,.rotater,.elem` have `transform-style: preserve-3d` and `.elem` have `translateZ`. I tried to fix this, but right now i have no idea what to do :(

Here is some part of css (better to check full-version on codepen):

```
.scene {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 200vw;
}
.level {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.rotater {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.7s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.elem {
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

  @for $i from 1 through $level1Elems {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      transform: rotateY(0 - ($i - 1) * $level1Angle) translateZ($level1Z);
    }
  }
}

.inner {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #EEEEEE;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 0.6rem 1rem 1rem rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.art-btn {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 10rem;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  border: 0.5rem solid;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}
```

Update: if i'm removing `transform-style: preserve-3d;` from `.rotater` all works fine in FF, but it completly breaks my layout :(

Update #2: http://codepen.io/suez/pen/7b889e66f096a65459b3994c4b4e2a07 - really simple recreation of bug. 5 elements, first have perspective, 2&3&4 have preserve-3d, 4 have translateZ(). You can select text in chrome and you can't do this in FF. If you will remove translateZ(-50vw) from 4 element, all will work as expected, but translateZ is absolutly must-have.

Update #3: i came up with hack for my pen (updated version here - http://codepen.io/suez/pen/b9cd3de42a464aa98579cd009e6e83a6?editors=010). I made `.rotater` 2px width/height, placed it in center, and changed `.elem` width/height to vw/vh units and added negative left/top so placed in center, like it was before. Anyway it still have minor problem, if user somehow hovers 2pxx/2px area of .rotater he loses button focus in FF :D But i can live with this.

Comment: It would help if you could reduce the example down to the bare minimum of HTML and CSS needed to reproduce the problem.  The amount of code there currently is probably discouraging people from trying to answer the question.

Comment: @phari http://codepen.io/suez/pen/7b889e66f096a65459b3994c4b4e2a07 - i recreated it here. Chrome works, FF not. Anyway i already found the hack (but not the civilized way :D) and will post it soon

Comment: http://codepen.io/suez/pen/bNKBmR - final version with hack.

Answer (score 0):

I Nikolay, I had a similar problem.

In a site (i can't link it, it's non alredy public) with elevator zoom, the zoomed image (with preserve-3d) z-index conflict with the z-index of the header (upper level). Seemed like header covered the image (but the header was on the top, and image under the header layout).

I put the transform-style at inital for that image.